# java check the properties values of the a object in the list

Tags: java

Actually i want to check if there is any user object with given username and password and return the user from the list of users. can you guys tell me the easiest way to implement that. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by user object ?

Comment: If you only have a list, iterate it and check each object. If you can create a map instead, or in addition to the list, look it up in a map.

Comment: using HashMap of username and password you can for existing users

Comment: well, i have an user class with properties username and password and i have list of all the users objects . and from the list of all the user i want to only select the specific user object having the  given username and password . if there is not such an users matching username and password then i want to send null value .. it is something like simple authentication.... thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do a Map of maps. The outer map being usernames, and the inner passwords. That is Map< String, Map< String, User >>
2. More appropriate might be to create an object User with {username, password} fields and do a Set which overrides equals and hash to something like this:

   ```
   class User {
     String username;
     String password;

     equals(Object other){
        return other.username.equals(this.username) && other.password.equals(this.password);
     }

     hashCode() { //hash the two values together
         return (username+password).hashCode();
     }
   ```

   }

And then have a Set of users Set< User >, called set.

```
    checkIfUserValid(String user, String password){
          u = new User(user, password);
          return set.contains(u);
    }
```

The benefit of the first approach the ability for example to delete a user with all of its passwords (if there are multiple password possible), in O(#passwords).. As opposed to the other approach which gives encapsulation, but will cost iteration over all users to check if user.username == usernameSoughtAfter;